# How to download a file as Blob from google drive using API

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, filesystems, firebase-storage

I have been working on a code that will download a blob from the google drive using their API(V3). I want to get this working as I need to duplicate the file from google drive to firebase storage by using the fileUrl/ fileID.

I am able to export the pdf file after following a blog on [medium](https://medium.com/@sandeepsinh/multiple-file-download-form-google-cloud-storage-using-python-and-gcs-api-1dbcab23c44)

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to:

1. [Get Drive file blob](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)
   You can get the `webContentLink` and open it to download the file. If you were to curl it you would get the file contents.
2. [Create a reference to the file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_files)

```
// Create a root reference
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

// Create a reference to 'mountains.jpg'
var mountainsRef = storageRef.child('mountains.jpg');
```

3. [Upload the Blob to the reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_blob_or_file)

```
 var file = ... // use the Blob you got on step 1
 ref.put(file).then(function(snapshot) {
   console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
 });
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the Google Drive API v3.

Server commands to get the file:

```js
/**
 * Gets a file from Google Drive using Service worker
 * @param fileId ID of the file to be retrieved
 * @returns File object
 * https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/get
 */
export const getFileMeta = async (fileId: string) => {
  const response = await drive.files.get({
    fileId: fileId,
    supportsAllDrives: true,
    fields: "*",
  })
  return response.data
}

export const getFileBlob = async (fileId: string) => {
  const response = await drive.files.get(
    {
      fileId: fileId,
      supportsAllDrives: true,
      // The response includes the file contents in the response body.
      alt: "media",
    },
    {
      responseType: "stream",
    }
  )
  return response.data
}

// `drive` object
const getDrive = () => {
  const authParams: { scopes: string[]; credentials: Record<string, string> } = {
    scopes: [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata",
    ],
    credentials: serviceWorkerCredentials,
  }
  const drive = googleDrive({
    version: "v3",
    auth: new gAuth.GoogleAuth(authParams),
  })

  return drive
}
```

API command requesting file (/api/google-drive/download-blob.ts)

```js
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  try {
    const fileMeta = await getFileMeta(fileId)
    const fileAsStream = await getFileBlob(fileId)
    const chunks: any[] = []
    for await (const chunk of fileAsStream) {
      chunks.push(chunk)
    }
    const fileAsBuffer = Buffer.concat(chunks)
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileMeta.name)
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", fileMeta.mimeType || "application/pdf")
    res.setHeader("Content-Length", fileMeta.size || 0)
    res.status(200)
    res.end(fileAsBuffer, "binary")
    return
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: "File download failed",
      success: false,
    })
  }
}
```

Client/Browser side requesting file:

```js
fetch(`/api/google-drive/download-blob`, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  body: JSON.stringify({ fileId }),
})
  .then((res) => {
    return res.blob()
  })
  .then((blob) => {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    const a = document.createElement("a")
    a.href = url
    a.download = fileName || "Unknown"
    document.body.appendChild(a)
    a.click()
  })
```

All of this is done with the NextJS framework. I hope it can help another get to the solution faster than I did. I am open to feedback to improve this.